# Careers 2.0 impressed by non-existent answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email

Careers recently sent me an email inviting me to join. Great! Except their email congratulated me on my excellent work in answering [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js) questions, and as it happens, [I've *never* answered a single Backbone.js related question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A313758+[backbone.js]). What's going on?

[image]

Comment: Been answering questions in your sleep again, have you?

Comment: But it's free. That's what you get for free.

Comment: You haven't even *edited* any [tag:backbone.js] questions, it looks like. Maybe it's impressed by your ability to have completely avoided that tag.

Comment: Do you own a DeLorean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, we mixed up some ids and effectively sent a batch of invites with random tags.  Rest assured, however:

1. We *did* mean to invite you, and
2. We *also* meant to invite some other person with exemplary [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js) activity

So, at least there's that...